# Pandoc: convert .docx to .tex while retaining the table structure from .docx format in output

Tags: tables, conversion, pandoc

The problem I have is that when I convert a document using Pandoc from .docx to .tex, the tables get messed up. Is there a way to use pandoc that will retain the proper table formatting in .tex?

.docx table formatting
[image: .docx table formatting]

.tex table formatting after conversion
[image: .tex table formatting]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Depends at last on your table. Complicated tables need handwork for an proper looking in LaTeX... I just saw your edit: the tex table is better, believe me.  Search here for tables and there typographie ...

Comment: Pandoc will convert the table but uses the longtable environment instead of the tabular environment. I need to use the tablular :/ Hi thanks for the welcome! :)

Comment: The TeX table is poor, nut it's much less poor than the original.  The manual for the `booktabs` package gives some excellent advice on well-formatted tables. If you really need identical (rather than superior) formatting for some reason, you may need to resort to hand-tweaking.  TeX is a powerful system; few conversions will be perfect.

Comment: I think the *structure* of the format is well preserved. Did you mean the *formatting* of the table? Do you miss the vertical line separators between columns and the left and right border lines?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Yes it was the vertical line separators I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Pandoc doesn't support the `tabular` table environment.

Someone announced in the Pandoc discussion forum about a year ago a separate Pandoc filter to achieve this:

- **https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/RUC-tuu_qf0/h-H3RRVt1coJ**

Comment: I was thinking about using the filter mechanism but found an alternative. Writer2latex http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/ seems to work better and uses xml config files to add or remove packages or formatting options. I'm still working out the kinks :)

Comment: The direct link now requires registration , but it can be still accessed with the Google cache: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:T6Nra1jFFxsJ:https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/RUC-tuu_qf0/m/TiUtOS-iAgAJ&hl=en&gl=es